# OneToOne Mapping with hibernate/JBoss/Seam

Tags: hibernate

I want to create a one to one mapping between the Entity Customer and OptIn. The OptIn Entity is optional.
That is why the foreign key must be in OptIn. At deployment I get the following error because the
mapping can not be found:

OneToOneSecondPass.java:135

Values:
   otherSide= optIn, mappedBy=customer

otherSideProperty = BinderHelper.findPropertyByName( otherSide, mappedBy );

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1130)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:296)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1115)
    ...

What can I do to get a correct mapping?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KPS_OPT_IN", schema = "EB")
public class OptIn extends KmsEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8818445355079384264L;


    private int id; /* kps_kunden_nr */

    private Customer customer;      

    public OptIn() {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "KPS_KUNDEN_NR", unique = true, nullable = false)    
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="KPS_KUNDEN_NR", referencedColumnName="KPS_KUNDEN_NR")   
    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
        this.setId(customer.getId());
    }    
}
```

---

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "KPS_KUNDEN", schema = "EB")
public class Customer extends KmsEntity implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private int id; 

    private OptIn optIn;

    public Customer() {
    }

    public Customer(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator="seqkpskunde")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="seqkpskunde",sequenceName="SEQ_KPS_KUNDE") 
    @Column(name = "KPS_KUNDEN_NR", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        if(optIn!=null){
            optIn.setId(id);
        }
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "customer")
    public OptIn getOptIn() {
        return optIn;
    }

    public void setOptIn(OptIn optIn) {
        this.optIn = optIn;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "foreign key must be in OptIn". You've mapped your `@OneToOne` association via `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` which means your entities will be linked via their ID values. It also means that:

1. You can't specify column names within `@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn` annotation; they will be taken from appropriate `@Id` columns on both entities instead.
2. Marking fetch as `LAZY` is pointless and going to be ignored; optional @OneToOne associations are **always** eagerly fetched.
3. The only way `OptIn` would be optional on this association is if there was no entry with given ID in the database.

What Hibernate / Annotations versions are you using?  If they're rather old it could be a bug in Hibernate code. But I believe it should work if you fix (1) and (2) above.

Comment: Thank you very much so far. I will will try this tomorrow.
Do you mean OptIn is only optional if the key/Id is in neither of both tables?

Comment: Customer is the owner of this relationship. So if you have a Customer with pk=314 and OptIn with pk=314, the relationship will be there. If you don't have an OptIn with pk=314, `Customer.optIn` property will be NULL.

Comment: Unfortunately I could not get it working if the id for the join is references from OptIn (mappedBy="customer"), only if I use the id in Customer. I am using hibernate 3.2.4sp1 and annotations 3.3.0GA. 
The solution with using the id from Customer is satisfactory for me.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your last comment. `mappedBy` is only applicable to FK-based associations (when you do it by PK, there's no association to maintain; it's implicit - thus specifying the "owner" end is pointless). The other end doesn't need to map anything at all. Look at the sample code here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1039

Comment: Yes you are right. It is a legacy database where there are customer records without a corresponding optin record and I thought, the optin record could be made optional if the key in the optin record is used.
I am now creating an optin record manually if it does not exist.