# How do I avoid NullPointerException with OneToOne mapping against a parent entity class?

Tags: java, hibernate, nullpointerexception, one-to-one

I have searched and found similar issues, but they don't quite seem to be the same problem as

- [Why am I getting this NullPointer exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681979/why-am-i-getting-this-nullpointer-exception)
- [OneToOne Mapping with hibernate/JBoss/Seam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638432/onetoone-mapping-with-hibernate-jboss-seam)
- [ANN-613 - NPE when mappedBy property is wrong on a @OneToOne](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-613)
- [ANN-558 - @OneToMany(mappedBy="") can not recognize properties in parent classes](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/ANN-558)
- [Hibernate Users - NPE with @Id on @OneToOne](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=970823)

I have a few entities mapped like this:

```
Person
  |
  +--User
```

I want to add a new entity `PersonPartDeux` with a OneToOne mapping to `Person`.  The resulting mapping should look something like this:

```
Person + PersonPartDeux
  |
  +--User
```

When I do so, a `NullPointerException` is thrown while trying to load the mapping:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.OneToOneSecondPass.doSecondPass(OneToOneSecondPass.java:135)
```

How do I specify the mapping so I can avoid this exception?

Here's my code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Person implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;

    @Version
    public int version = 0;

    public String name;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    public PersonPartDeux personPartDeux;
}

@Entity
public class PersonPartDeux implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "person-primarykey")
    @GenericGenerator(
        name = "person-primarykey",
        strategy = "foreign",
        parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "person")
    )
    public Long id = null;

    @Version
    public int version = 0;

    @OneToOne(optional=false, mappedBy="person")
    public Person person;

    public String someText;
}

@Entity
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "person_Id")
public class User extends Person
{
    public String username;
    public String password;
}
```

As for why I'm bothering, I need both the inheritance and the `OneToOne` mapping to solve different known issues in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attach the Hibernate source to your project, so you can click thru or 'Open Type' (Ctrl-Shift-T in Eclipse) to view the OneToOneSecondPass source.

Seeing the source, will give you a clear indication as to what needs to be specified.

In my source (Hibernate 4.1.7), line 135 is

```
propertyHolder.addProperty( prop, inferredData.getDeclaringClass() );
```

However you're probably using an earlier version.

Looking at the mappings, I'm suspicious of the @OneToOne definition -- mappedBy="person".

```
@OneToOne(optional=false, mappedBy="person")
public Person person;
```

What does it usefully mean, to map an association property by itself?  Hibernate already knows the property is a OneToOne -- you just told it that.

Pointing the underpinning mapping/ FK of the property, at itself.. probably isn't actually telling Hibernate any correct or useful information.

Here's an example from the HB dosc, perhaps showing better how to do what you want:

```
@Entity
class MedicalHistory implements Serializable {
  @Id Integer id;

  @MapsId @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "patient_id")
  Person patient;
}

@Entity
class Person {
  @Id @GeneratedValue Integer id;
}
```

Source:  http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/
(3.5 docs off JBoss site.)

Cheers, hope this helps.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787698/jpa-hibernate-one-to-one-relationship - I have a shared primary key which this answer claims doesn't work unless I do this mapping.

Comment: And yeah, I'm using the Hibernate version that comes with Seam 2.0.1.GA, which I can't really upgrade right now :)

Comment: You were right about that mapping.  Changing `mappedBy="person"` to `mappedBy="personPartDeux"` solved it for my example.  Unfortunately this isn't the problem in my *real* code, so I'm going to have to dig further for a real repro of my problem.  I'll do that in another question, since you answered the one I've asked here.